# connecting RC circuit to s-function block in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, simscape

Can I connect an RC circuit from the Simscape library (as a feedback) to an s-function block and apply a time series as input? I am trying to use the `Linearize` tool from Control Design to obtain the frequency response of the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You need to use the [PS-Simulink Converter](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/physmod/simscape/ref/pssimulinkconverter.html) block to convert the physical signals from your electrical sensor blocks to Simulink signals, and the [Simulink-PS Converter](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/physmod/simscape/ref/simulinkpsconverter.html) block to convert the Simulink signals from your S-function into physical signals to feed into electrical source blocks. Beware of creating algebraic loops though.

Comment: I did so..but I do not know how to draw the transfer function of the whole system in simulink

Comment: `linearize` is the correct way to do it, you can also use the Linear Analysis Tool. See [Linearize Simulink Model at Model Operating Point](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/slcontrol/ug/linearize-simulink-model.html) for an example.